# How to list all selected elements in python?

Tags: python

If I select a face of a cube and switch over to the internal Python console and pass:

```
bpy.context.selected_objects
```

I get:

```
[bpy.data.objects['Cube']]
```

instead of something like `[bpy.data.objects['Cube'].f[1]]`.

Coming from Maya I was looking for something like:

```
import pymel.core as pc

print pc.ls(sl=True)
```

which in the above case would return the face id.

Same thing applies for vertices and edges.

How can I go about getting a detailed selection list programmatically?

Answer (score 6):

You may be interested into bmesh module's [select_history](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMesh.select_history)

```
import bpy
import bmesh

me = bpy.context.object.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

for elem in bm.select_history:
    print(repr(elem))

# Variant 1 - get the active edge
try:
    active_edge = filter(lambda elem: isinstance(elem, bmesh.types.BMEdge), 
        reversed(bm.select_history)).__next__()
except StopIteration:
    active_edge = None


# Variant 2 - same, but less geeky ;)

for elem in reversed(bm.select_history):
    if isinstance(elem, bmesh.types.BMEdge):
        active_edge = elem
        break
else:
    active_edge = None


# Get selected faces in order

for elem in bm.select_history:
    if isinstance(elem, bmesh.types.BMFace):
        print(repr(elem))


# Get all selected faces
# Note: bm.select_history lacks geometry selected via border select, lasso, etc.
#       (mass-selection operators)!

for face in bm.faces:
    if face.select:
        print(repr(face))
```

Answer (score 4):

PyMEL's [`ls`](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/PyMel/generated/functions/pymel.core.general/pymel.core.general.ls.html#pymel.core.general.ls) seems to roll several related functions into one (match by type, name, regexp-pattern, etc.). There's no such function built in to Blender's Python API, so you must create selection list manually.

You have to know what element you need to process. If it's a list of [`MeshVertex`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.types.MeshVertex.html), [`MeshEdge`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.types.MeshEdge.html) or [`MeshPolygon`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.types.MeshPolygon.html), filter out objects whose [`type`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.type) isn't `"MESH"`. It's also possible that edit-mode and object-mode data isn't synced, which will happen if the script is run when the object is in edit-mode (presumably while the user's selecting elements). To make the correct selection list regardless of the object's state, run [`update_from_editmode`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.update_from_editmode) beforehand. Then you can create the list:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
mesh = obj.data # Assumed that obj.type == 'MESH'
obj.update_from_editmode() # Loads edit-mode data into object data

selected_polygons = [p for p in mesh.polygons if p.select]
selected_edges = [e for e in mesh.vertices if e.select]
selected_vertices = [v for v in mesh.vertices if v.select]

# ... process selection list...
```

This also applies to the newer mesh editing API [`bmesh`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bmesh.html) and also other object types (check the API doc's [index](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/genindex.html#S) if the element needed has a `select*` attribute), though can be a bit more involving for some types. For example, a curve object can contain more than one spline, so iteration over each splines must be [chain](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)ed in some way to reach all [`BezierSplinePoint`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.types.BezierSplinePoint.html):

```
import bpy
from itertools import chain

obj = bpy.context.object
curve = obj.data # Assumed that obj.type == 'CURVE'
obj.update_from_editmode() # Loads edit-mode data into object data

selected_cpoints = [p for p in chain(*[s.bezier_points for s in curve.splines])
                    if p.select_control_point]

# ... process selection list...
```

Answer (score 3):

In blender there is a difference between an *object* and elements such as *faces*, *edges*, and *vertices*.

I don't know if a collection of selected elements is stored anywhere, but you can iterate through every face and check if it's selected via [`polygon.select`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bpy.types.MeshPolygon.html#bpy.types.MeshPolygon.select):

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

for poly in ob.data.polygons:
    if poly.select == True:
        # Do stuff
```

Note that you must be in object mode for this to work.