# bmesh/python - list directly or indirectly connected verts

Tags: python, bmesh

For a single vertex, how can I create a list of all the vertices connected directly or indirectly to it?
Similar to *Select Linked* but without actually selecting anything.

Comment: If there's no better way, you could Select linked, get a list of selected vertices and deselect all. Check http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5781/how-to-list-all-selected-elements-in-python

Comment: You can get the edges the vertex is part of, then get their vertices (but exclude the verts you already visited). But Select linked is still better, because it uses native code and superior bmesh walkers.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the following definitions are a correct interpretation of what you are asking...

> directly: connected by a single edge
>
> indirectly: connected through a continuous path of N edges

...then the following code will find all directly or indirectly connected vertices of a given vertex. findConnectedVerts() takes the vertex of interest plus a maximum depth as arguments. It will then recursively find the connected vertices. I've tested this on a cube to verify that depth 1 yields the directly connected vertices, depth 2 yields all but a single vertex (which is 3 away) and depth 3 yields all the vertices in the cube (well, not the vertex passed in).

Note: I wasn't considering performance only functionality

```
import bpy

def getEdgesForVertex(v_index, mesh, marked_edges):
    all_edges = [e for e in mesh.edges if v_index in e.vertices]
    unmarked_edges = [e for e in all_edges if e.index not in marked_edges]
    return unmarked_edges

def findConnectedVerts(v_index, mesh, connected_verts, marked_edges, maxdepth=1, level=0):  
    if level >= maxdepth:
        return

    edges = getEdgesForVertex(v_index, mesh, marked_edges)

    for e in edges:
        othr_v_index = [idx for idx in mesh.edges[e.index].vertices if idx != v_index][0]
        connected_verts[othr_v_index] = True
        marked_edges.append(e.index)
        findConnectedVerts(othr_v_index, mesh, connected_verts, marked_edges, maxdepth=maxdepth, level=level+1)

def main():
    mesh = bpy.context.object.data
        
    connected_verts = {}
    marked_edges = []

    findConnectedVerts(0, mesh, connected_verts, marked_edges, maxdepth=1)
    print(",".join([str(v) for v in connected_verts.keys()]))

    connected_verts = {}
    marked_edges = []

    findConnectedVerts(0, mesh, connected_verts, marked_edges, maxdepth=2)
    print(",".join([str(v) for v in connected_verts.keys()]))

    connected_verts = {}
    marked_edges = []
    
    findConnectedVerts(0, mesh, connected_verts, marked_edges, maxdepth=3)
    print(",".join([str(v) for v in connected_verts.keys()]))

main()
```

Comment: I must say the use of the global variables makes me uncomfortable.  I would turn them into explicit function parameters.

Comment: Fair enough, updated to remove globals and avoid your discomfort. :)